# print success messages for asserts in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, assertion

I am using assert in python. Every time an assert fails I get the failure message which I would have put there to be printed. I was wondering if there is a way to print a custom success message when the assert condition passes?

I am using py.test framework.

for instance:

```
assert self.clnt.stop_io()==1, "IO stop failed"
```

for the above assert I get message "IO stop failed" if assert fails but I am looking to have "IO stop succeeded" if assert passes. something like this:

```
 assert self.clnt.stop_io()==1, "IO stop failed", "IO stop succeeded"
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the simplest is surely to place a print below the assert:

```
assert self.clnt.stop_io()==1, "IO stop failed"
print("IO stop passed at location ==1")
```

Comment: that's right. i thought about this one. 
the real worry is the internal framework that we have is designed in such a way as to ignore certain tests (asserts) in some scenarios and continue further. 
and in those scenarios, would this not be a false message which would get printed no matter assert passed or failed?

Comment: Yes, if somehow the assert is ignored, the following instruction will be executed, giving you a wrong feedback. You need to tell us how the asserts are skipped here.

Answer (score 8):

Write a simple helper function:

```
def myfunc(msg='assert OK'):
    print msg
    return True
```

Include that in the condition on the right-side, after an `and`:

```
assert self.clnt.stop_io()==1 and myfunc("IO stop succeeded"), "IO stop failed"
```

Comment: without extra function, but ugly: `assert self.clnt.stop_io()==1 and not print("IO stop succeeded"), "IO stop failed"`

Answer (score 7):

This has been added to the pytest module v5 as the hook [pytest_assertion_pass](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-5-0-0-2019-06-28)

in your conftest.py

```
def pytest_assertion_pass(item, lineno, orig, expl):
    log.info("asserting that {}, {}, {}, {}".format(item, lineno, orig, expl))
```

and in pytest.ini

```
enable_assertion_pass_hook = true
```

Answer (score 3):

I would combine @dashingdw and @Reblochon Masque solution

```
def my_assert(condition, fail_str, suc_str):
    assert condition, fail_str
    print suc_str
```

From my point of view this is less "dangerous" and you don't need to insert an additional `print` line every time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really feeling adventurous, you can just write your own extensible assert wrapper - with which you can count the number of asserts failed or add functionality like testing in quiet or verbose modes
eg:

```
def assert(condition, fail_str, suc_str):
     if condition:
          print fail_str
     else:
          num_tests_passed = num_tests_passed + 1
          if verbose_enabled:
              print suc_str
```