# How can I overload\override Python's assert statement to print when assertion passes

Tags: python, assert

With Python's assert command I can print a message when the assertion fails

**Python Console:**

```
>>> assert 0, "FAIL"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: FAIL
```

I would like to keep the same statement structure by overloading\overriding the assert.
I don't want to implement a new function named my_assert(condition, msg_fail, msg_pass) to use instead of "assert", like suggested in [print success messages for asserts in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36834677/317460),

I would like to keep the same one line structure as shown below.
Is there a way, without wrapping assert in a try:except, to output a message when assert succeeds? Some way to override the assert statement so it works in a different way, Something like:

```
>>> assert 1, "FAIL", "PASS"
PASS
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just put that logic in a convenience function

```
def print_assert(condition, str_fail, str_pass):
    assert condition, str_fail
    print(str_pass)
```

Then use it the same way

```
>>> print_assert(1, "FAIL", "PASS")
PASS
>>> print_assert(0, "FAIL", "PASS")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print_assert(0, "FAIL", "PASS")
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 2, in print_assert
    assert condition, str_fail
AssertionError: FAIL
```

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer. I modified my question to clarify that I am looking for a way to keep the keyword assert and continue using it, but not replace it with a method that wraps the assert.